# How to pass List<String> as value into json body in Flutter API call

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, http

In Postman, I am passing value as picture. And getting success response also.
I have been trying to POST the API with this value through code but no luck yet.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far in Dart? How are you creating the JSON?

Comment: With a Map<string, dynamic> ?

Comment: Are you using from Dio!?

Comment: thnx all of U, for your quick response. finally I solved it r8 now :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this way

```
Map data = {
  "employee_id": Utils.EID,
  "meals": mealChecked,     //where mealCheckd = [Dinner, Sahri, Lunch]
  "area": area,
  "date": date
};

var body = jsonEncode(data);
```

finally pass it to http body

```
var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer ${prefs.getString("token")}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
      body: body,
    );
```